# UseState to control

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use a button to control the audio player mute but it makes the player default mute, I want that only mute when clicking.How to edit it

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactAudioPlayer from "react-audio-player";

const Test = () => {
  const [ismute, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <><div>
      <ReactAudioPlayer
        controls
        muted={ismute ? "false": "True"}
        src='https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3'
        loop
        autoPlay
         />
    </div><button onClick={() => setOpen(!ismute)}>click me!</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Test
```

Comment: `muted={ismute ? false: true }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing as `string`,

```
muted={ismute ? "false": "True"}
```

since the initial value of the `ismute` is `false` as:

```
const [ismute, setMute] = useState(false);
```

then what you are going to pass as a prop is `True` or `false` which is `truthy` value which makes `ismute` as always mute

For state ismute, initially assign value true instead of false as below:

```
const [ismute, setOpen] = useState(true);
```

You should pass `muted` prop as either `true` or `false`. You are passing as a string

```
muted={ismute ? false: true }
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo] **`I've created a simulation for player`**

Answer (score 0):

For state ismute, initially assign value true instead of false as below:

```
const [ismute, setOpen] = useState(true);
```

Another correction might be at component *ReactAudioPlayer*:

```
<ReactAudioPlayer
    controls
    muted={ismute}
    src='https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3'
    loop
    autoPlay
     />
```

Comment: Sorry dude, I was updating my answer, but by mistake updated yours